# R knitr's Build Code Appendix not working

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to build a code appendix using the instructions from Yihui's site below:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/code-appendix.html

The issues is that I get no results, nothing happens when I preview the code in RStudio.  One thing that I noticed is that code `knitr::all_labels()` returns `NULL` even though I have named all 30+ chunks in my Rnotebook.  Also, I was able to build a external file with `purl` which is the last line.  I tried to build a reprex with a basic starter Rnotebook, but the reprex didn't build in RStudio so I am going to paste what tried.

Thank you!

The Code...sorry, I had to remove the back ticks so that I could paste all the code chunks together.

```
---
title: "Reprex for Code Appendix"
author: 'ME'
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: hide
---

{r setup, echo = TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  message = FALSE, 
  warning = FALSE, 
  # cache = TRUE,
  dev.args = list(pointsize = 11)
)
options(digits = 3, width = 80)



This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

{r test}
plot(cars)


Add a new chunk by clicking the *Insert Chunk* button on the toolbar or by pressing *Ctrl+Alt+I*.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will be saved alongside it (click the *Preview* button or press *Ctrl+Shift+K* to preview the HTML file).

The preview shows you a rendered HTML copy of the contents of the editor. Consequently, unlike *Knit*, *Preview* does not run any R code chunks. Instead, the output of the chunk when it was last run in the editor is displayed.

# Appendix: All code for this report

{r Code, ref.label=knitr::all_labels(), echo=TRUE}


{r get-labels, echo = FALSE}
labs = knitr::all_labels()
labs = setdiff(labs, c("setup", "get-labels"))


{r all-code, ref.label=labs, eval=FALSE}


{r, ref.label=knitr::all_labels(),echo=TRUE,eval=FALSE}


THIS DID WORK - BUILT A NEW FILE WITH THE CODE!!!!
{r code=readLines(knitr::purl('./Reprex_for_Code_Appendix.Rmd', documentation = 1)), eval = FALSE}
```

The Output:

```
Reprex for Code Appendix
ME
2020-03-16
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  message = FALSE, 
  warning = FALSE, 
  # cache = TRUE,
  dev.args = list(pointsize = 11)
)
options(digits = 3, width = 80)
This is an R Markdown Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code.

Try executing this chunk by clicking the Run button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

plot(cars)
Add a new chunk by clicking the Insert Chunk button on the toolbar or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+I.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will be saved alongside it (click the Preview button or press Ctrl+Shift+K to preview the HTML file).

The preview shows you a rendered HTML copy of the contents of the editor. Consequently, unlike Knit, Preview does not run any R code chunks. Instead, the output of the chunk when it was last run in the editor is displayed.

Appendix: All code for this report
THIS DID WORK - BUILT A NEW FILE WITH THE CODE!!!!
```

`sessioninfo::session_info()`

```
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2020-03-16                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 package         * version    date       lib source        
 anomalize         0.2.0      2019-09-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 anytime           0.3.7      2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 assertthat        0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 backports         1.1.5      2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 base64enc         0.1-3      2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 bit               1.1-15.2   2020-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 bit64             0.9-7      2017-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 blob              1.2.1      2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 broom             0.5.5      2020-02-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)        
 callr             3.4.2      2020-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cellranger        1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cli               2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 colorspace        1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 crayon            1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 data.table        1.12.8     2019-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 DBI               1.1.0      2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 dbplyr            1.4.2      2019-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 desc              1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 devtools          2.2.2      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 digest            0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 dplyr           * 0.8.4      2020-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ellipsis          0.3.0      2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 evaluate          0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fable           * 0.1.2      2020-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fabletools      * 0.1.2      2020-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fansi             0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 farver            2.0.3      2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fastmap           1.0.1      2019-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 feasts          * 0.1.2      2020-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 forcats         * 0.5.0      2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fs                1.3.1      2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 generics          0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ggplot2         * 3.3.0      2020-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 glue              1.3.1      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 gtable            0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 haven             2.2.0      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 highr             0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 hms               0.5.3      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 htmltools         0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 httpuv            1.5.2      2019-09-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 httr              1.4.1      2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 jsonlite          1.6.1      2020-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 kableExtra        1.1.0      2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 knitr           * 1.28       2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 labeling          0.3        2014-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 later             1.0.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lattice           0.20-38    2018-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lifecycle         0.2.0      2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)      
 lubridate         1.7.4      2018-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 magrittr          1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 memoise           1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 mime              0.9        2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 miniUI            0.1.1.1    2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 modelr            0.1.6      2020-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 multidplyr        0.0.0.9000 2020-02-29 [1] local         
 munsell           0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 nlme              3.1-144    2020-02-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pillar            1.4.3      2019-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgbuild          1.0.6      2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgconfig         2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgload           1.0.2      2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 prettyunits       1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 processx          3.4.2      2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 promises          1.1.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ps                1.3.2      2020-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 purrr           * 0.3.3      2019-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 R6                2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 Rcpp              1.0.3      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 readr           * 1.3.1      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 readxl            1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 remotes           2.1.1      2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 reprex            0.3.0      2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rlang             0.4.5      2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rmarkdown         2.1        2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 RODBC             1.3-16     2019-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 RPostgres       * 1.2.0      2019-12-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rprojroot         1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rstudioapi        0.11       2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rvest             0.3.5      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 scales            1.1.0      2019-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 sessioninfo       1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 shiny           * 1.4.0      2019-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 sodium            1.1        2017-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 stringi           1.4.6      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 stringr         * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 testthat          2.3.2      2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tibble          * 2.1.3      2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 tibbletime        0.1.3      2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyr           * 1.0.2      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyselect        1.0.0      2020-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyverse       * 1.3.0      2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tsibble         * 0.8.6      2020-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 urca              1.3-0      2016-09-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 usethis           1.5.1      2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 utf8              1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 vctrs             0.2.3      2020-02-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 viridisLite       0.3.0      2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 webshot           0.5.2      2019-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 whisker           0.4        2019-08-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 withr             2.1.2      2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xfun              0.12       2020-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xml2              1.2.2      2019-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xtable            1.8-4      2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 yaml              2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)

[1] C:/Apps/R/R_LIBS_USER
[2] C:/Apps/R/R-3.6.3/library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knitr::all_labels()` returns `NULL` if it is not called in the full knitting process. When you run a single code chunk in the R Markdown Notebook, the document is not fully knitted.

To make `knitr::all_labels()` return all chunk labels, you should not use the notebook mode or preview the notebook, but knit the document instead (e.g., to the `html_document` output format).

Comment: Hello Yihui! Thanks you recommendation worked, but I have a couple of clarifying questions.  First, the Appendix not only printed the code, but also produced the output...is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Second, should I be using Rnotebooks? When would I use html_notebook vs. html_document?  Thanks!